# How to use Volume Shadows Copy and Robocopy on Win7?

Tags: robocopy, volume-shadow-service

I’d like to backup my system with Robocopy and Powersell but Robocopy is not able to copy opened files.
Volume Shadows Copy seems a solution but I don’t find any clear and simple explanation how to use it.

Do you have any idea?

I’m running on Windows 7 x64 Enterprise.
Thanks for your help.
Franck

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a programming-related question and answer site, and your question is off-topic here. Voting to migrate it to [superuser](http://superuser.com), which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform a VSS snapshot on Windows 7, you can simply do a "System Restore". After, open an administrator console, type `vssadmin list shadows`. You are looking for the "Shadow Copy Volume" line in the most recent snapshot. Copy this, and do `mountvol X: YOUR_VSS_PATH`, and your VSS snap will be mounted on X:. After that, run robocopy on X: and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the VSS shadow using `mklink` command. This Works in Servers and Workstations.

`mklink` is a native tool.

For example:

```
mklink /D C:\shadow_volume_1 \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1\
```

More information can be found here: http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Mount_shadow_volumes_on_disk_images